# Is there tutorial available for Agro Uml Xmi

Tags: uml, xmi, tool-uml, argouml

Have created the Sequence diagram using ArgoUML and exported it as XMI.
I need to identify the class,function and their relationships by parsing the XMI.
I can able to parse the class and their corresponding operation and attribute as explained in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-wxxm24/#resources

Can any one help me in parsing the association role and classifier role in order to obtain their relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing that you need to know is that it's UML 1.4/1.5 serialized using XMI 1.2.  ArgoUML uses the NetBeans UML/XMI support for writing these files, but it's been long since retired.

Good luck!